# Set a new field based on calculations in MongoDB update statement

Tags: mongodb

I use the attribute pattern approach in my collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: "id1",
    _cells: [
      { k: "key1", v: "value1" },
      { k: "key2", v: "value2" },
      { k: "key3", v: "value3" },
    ]
  },
  // another records
]
```

I need a new field that will contain key information from `_cells` like this:

```
  {
    _id: "id1",
    new_field: "value1_value2",   // without key3
    _cells: [
      { k: "key1", v: "value1" },
      { k: "key2", v: "value2" },
      { k: "key3", v: "value3" },
    ]
  },
```

I'm looking for something like this but don't know how to do it correctly:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { new_field: { $concat: [ "$_cells.$[$_cells[k]=='key_1'].v", "$_cells.$[$_cells[k]=='key_2'].v" ] } } }
)
```

**Update**:
New key was appended

Answer (score 1):

The `$concat` is an aggregation operator, it can not support normal queries, try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

You just need to wrap the update part in array bracket `[]`,

- `$indexOfArray` to find the array index of `key1` key and same as `key2` key
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element's value from `_cells` array by passing above index
- `$concat` to concat both the key's value by `_` character

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      new_field: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$_cells.v",
              { $indexOfArray: ["$_cells.k", "key1"] } // pass key1
            ]
          },
          "_",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$_cells.v",
              { $indexOfArray: ["$_cells.k", "key2"] } // pass key2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SUvqRyVpkY5)

Comment: Thank you, it's suitable for me. In case indexOfArray found nothing we get -1 and so the last element from array _cells but in my case it is not so important.